# Proper code structure for a Servlet using caching and async

Tags: java, design-patterns, async, servlet

I'm using an Java Servlet (with embedded Jetty, no Spring, no frameworks) and I'm adding asynchronous processing and caching to it. The exact implementation is irrelevant to this question and it's not very Java-specific. My problem is the overall code structure, which before the additions looks like this pseudocode

```
void service1() {
    addFixedHeaders();

    try {
        service2();
    } catch (MyException e) {
       ...
    } catch (AnotherException e) {
      ...
    }

    addMoreHeadersUnlessAlreadySet();
    writeResponse();
}

void service2() {
   addCorsIfNeeded();
   if (needsForwarding())  {
       doForwarding();
   } else {
       service3();
   }
}

void service3() {
    if (hasEtag() && isStillValid()) {
       serveMotModified();
    } else {
        service4();
    }
}
```

Basically, it's a sequence of calls `service1 -> service2 -> service3 -> ...` with some pre- and postprocessing (kind of inline [FilterChain](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/FilterChain.html)), where some calls are conditional. I used to be satisfied with it.

However, adding caching (I mean serving 200 response from server cache rather than serving 304, which fits nicely) requires changes in multiple methods. This gets complicated by caching static and dynamic content differently and using the same cache also for avoiding compression. This makes the code rather ugly, while I'd prefer some functional style like

```
return cache.getOrCompute(key, key -> someComputation(key))
```

Independently, as an experiment, I've also added asynchronous processing (which is needed for some requests only). This required a major rewrite and lead to something exceptionally awful (and would get even worse when caching was added). I'm thinking about something like this chain

```
void service1() {
    process1();
    if (isSimple1()) {
       shortcut1();
    } else if (wantsAsync1()) {
        callAsync(service2); 
    } else {
        service2(); 
    }
}
```

when most methods will have only some parts. What I dislike here, is that there's no possibility to handle exceptions in a single place (like my in first `service1`. It also forces me to move the postprocessing to some `service99` which doesn't make obvious, that it always happens.

I wonder, if there's a suitable pattern, something like promise chaining or whatever (I'm not looking for a library though I don't insist on reinventing the wheel). Something simple, yet flexible, so that further additions fits nicely in the pattern.

Comment: Q1: Why don't you handle all exceptions in a separate servlet? Q2: Why don't you implement caching as an actual filter?

Comment: @scriptin Can you elaborate? Q1: How would a separate servlet know what exception occured? When and how would I call it? Q2: Should the filter read the cached value from the response *output* stream? How would it avoid extracting data from the request the same way the servlet does?

Comment: Q1: See [this example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-exception-handling.htm), Q2: It depends on what you want to cache and on which level (request-response level, services level, etc.); see [javaee-cache-filter](https://github.com/samaxes/javaee-cache-filter) for some examples. It would not avoid extracting data, but it would separate the concerns. The main issue I see in your code is that you put everything in one place, which creates a [big ball of mud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud)

Comment: @scriptin Q1: Thank you. It doesn't really fit, but was helpful. Q2: In the end, I want to cache everything as much as possible: 1. 304 NOT MODIFIED, 2. static resources, 3. dynamic resources once I get the invalidation working, 4. compression (when I get a cache miss, compute the `etag` (which is globally unique) and find out that there's already matching compressed data). `+++` "big ball of mud" - that's why I'm asking here. I've improved the code in the meantime a lot (it's 34 lines calling 10 methods in a linear fashion and writing some stats).

Comment: Since you have 4 points in your caching list, I'd suggest implementing them as 4 filters. Instead of fighting Servlet architecture it's better to follow it. It has its flaws, but since you decided to not use any frameworks, it's the next best thing.

Comment: @scriptin I doubt this is efficiently possible, especially for point 4. The servlet computes/obtains the uncompressed data, computes the `etag` and sees that it matches some already cached data. The filter would've to obtain the uncompressed data, i.e., it had to call the chain with its own `ServletOutputStream` created for this purpose only. `+++` Similarly for the input as multiple filters need to be able to read the input data and an `InputStream` can be read just once. Within a single Servlet, I can drain it to a `byte[]` and read it as often I need.